# Which javac compiler settings would you expect as default when using an open source library?

Tags: java, ant, build, javac

I have recently had feedback about my open source library [jOOQ](http://jooq.sourceforge.net)'s binaries not being delivered with debug information. That was good feedback. I never noticed this, because I never debugged the binaries when running integration tests.

This incident led me to an interesting question:

> Which **javac** compiler settings and options would you choose / expect as default when using an open source library?

Note:

- I'm using ant to build, so please refer to the [ant javac task API](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html).
- I **know** how the options work. No need to explain me. I'm curious about **which ones** to choose.
- The source is available to my users, and the deliverable can easily be rebuilt, so the user can change their settings if they need to optimise for a special case.
- **EDIT**: I especially appreciate **concrete** answers referencing **concrete** options. I know that good work is expected :-)

Comment: The debug option is -g on the command line but something like debug="true" in ant.

Comment: Hi Peter. That's not my question. I know **how** to set the options, but I'm curious about **which ones** to choose

Comment: I was under the impression that javac was pretty much always run without special options.

Comment: @Brendan: Check out the ant task's documentation: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html. By default, no debug information is added to the binaries. This saves space but makes debugging an open source library a major pain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable as much debug info as you possibly can, do not obfuscate, and have a source download corresponding to your binary.

Essentially you should give the best possible conditions for single-stepping through your code in case of problems.  A developer may have to identify failing conditions to avoid triggering some code or similar, and in that situation you need all the help you can get.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if one of your library's users encounters a problem, would you prefer a bug report with a stacktrace with line numbers or without?  I know which one i would prefer.

I've used lots of java libraries, mainly open source, but a few closed as well.  about the only libraries which don't include debug info are the closed source libraries which have been run through an obfuscator.

Comment: OK, thanks. I can see the debug option is very obvious. What about other options?

Comment: What other options actually affect the generated classes?  Other than maybe the target version, i can't think of any other relevant setting besides debug.  As for the target version, 1.5 is a good target as it includes some of the newer features but covers a pretty good time range.  There are not too many libs providing 1.4 compatible classes.

Comment: I guess you're right. Although I might have unconsciously used some 1.6 API, like String.isEmpty() or stuff like that...